# windows 2003 cannot remote to windows 8 with firewall off on windows 8

Tags: windows, connection, windows-server-2003, rdp

I installed windows 8 on my laptop and turned the windows 8 firewall off.
And I've enabled "Allow Remote Assistance connections to this computer" and "Allow this computer be controlled remotely" in Windows 8.

But when I use "mstsc" (from another PC with windows 2003 installed) to remote to windows 8, it gives me an error "Client cannot connect to remote machine".

Does windows 8 support RDP connections from OS windows 2003 or earlier?

If I remote the 2003 from the Windows 8, everything works fine.
Is there any other configurations that prevent windows 8 being connected from windows 2003?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Windows 8 supports RDP connections from Windows 2003 or earlier. To achieve this you need to allow connections from computers running any version of RDP client. There's an according setting in the system settings of your Windows 8 machine (Desktop Control Panel, at the place where remote access is being turned on). Without that setting only computers with Network Level Authentication (NLA) are allowed to connect, and NLA is only supported from Vista and later.

Comment: Thanks for your feedback, actually I don't have Remote Desktop Region below the Remote Assistance region.  Not sure how to make it to display.  I used the Windows 8 Standard version (not pro version).
So not sure whether standard version Windows 8 supports Remote Desktop settings that you mentioned.

Comment: You need Windows 8 Pro to accept RDP connections